# AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Code:

```
import turtle
import random
turtle.penup()
for i in range(20):
    x=random.randint(-200,200)
    y=random.randint(-200,200)
    turtle.setposition(x,y)
    turtle.dot()
turtle.done()
```

Error:

```
F:\Python>random.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\random.py", line 2, in <module>
    import random
  File "F:\Python\random.py", line 5, in <module>
    x=random.randint(-200,200)
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'
```

Comment: Is your file named `random.py`?

Comment: Name your file something else (...not `turtle.py`).

Answer (score 6):

Rename your file.

Make sure that no files are named random.py.

Comment: Wow, I had the same exact problem. Thanks. But, is there a reason why it should never be named random.py?

Comment: :) The best answer ever :) Thx.!