# Attribute Error while using random module

Tags: python, random, attributeerror

I am trying the below program, but getting Attribute error . Can someone help me solve this issue?

```
import random

print(random.randrange(1, 10))
```

```
Attribute error: partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'randrange'(most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Your code works for me. In your real code you haven't overridden the `random` module with a local variable called `random` have you?

Comment: Is your own script named `random.py`?  *That's* what would be found by `import random`, rather than the intended module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599350/attributeerror-module-random-has-no-attribute-randint)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have named your file or srcipt as random.py , that is causing confusion with the random module .